Rejne style (fncychap package) customisation issues
I've been trying to do the following but failing:

Change the default black border colour of the box to a gradient border.
Pair Chapter Name with Chapter Number instead of having the Chapter Name outside the box and above the number.
Control the inner-box padding or Chapter Title margins - currently, having a longer Chapter Title appears crammed with the border.

This is what i currently have:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\RequirePackage{times}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap} % alternative styles: Rejne, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Bjornstrup, Sonny.

% The colours I want to use for the gradient border of the Rejne layout box.
\definecolor{custom_purple}{HTML}{611060}
\definecolor{custom_red}{HTML}{E4230E}

% Currently hiding the "Chapter" text and only show the chapter number and title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{} 
\makeatother

\ChTitleVar{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\hspace{20pt}}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.}

\end{document}



if you need such fancy things like boxes with gradients, I would suggest to have a look at the tcolorbox package. Here a simple example how to place chapter titles in a tcolorbox: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687992/36296

... and here how to make a gradient frame with a tcolorbox https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/662482/36296

Thank you, I'll give it a go!

I've managed to create the chapter style I wanted thanks to the comments by  @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I'm sharing my solution here with some comments for guidance, in case someone else might be looking to do something similar:
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{chapterStyleBox}[1][]{
    colback=white, 
    fonttitle=\Large\sffamily\color{purple}, 
    colbacktitle=white,
    title={#1}, % In this case, title acts as the text for the chapter number
    frame style={left color=purple, right color=red}, % For the gradient
    enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-5mm},
    boxed title style={colframe=white, colback=white, overlay},
    fontupper=\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}\centering, % In this case, this acts as the content style for the text of the chapter title
    width=\textwidth,
    boxsep=30pt,
    #1
}

\makeatletter
\setlength\midchapskip{0pt}
% Applying the new 'chapterStyleBox' tcolorbox as my custom chapter style
\makechapterstyle{myStyle}{
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}      
    \renewcommand\printchaptername{}    
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{}     
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{
        \ifnum\value{chapter}=0 % Check if the chapter number is zero (i.e., unnumbered) - only show the chapter title
            \begin{chapterStyleBox} 
            #1 
            \end{chapterStyleBox}
        \else % else, if there is a chapter number, show both the chapter number and title
            \begin{chapterStyleBox}[title=Chapter \thechapter\quad] 
            #1 
            \end{chapterStyleBox}
        \fi
    }
}

\makeatother
% Applying my custom chapter style globally
\chapterstyle{myStyle}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Chapter title without numbering}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter title with numbering}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{A longer chapter title that spans multiple lines}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}


Output:



